# What is the issue in the following node.js mySQL query?

Tags: mysql, node.js

=================================================

## > here is a query to be stored in a variable

```
  let x = tempCont.query('SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` =' + req.body.user_name,
                function (err, result, field) {
                    if (!!error) {
                        console.log('Error in user_name Query');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(result);
  }
                    console.log(x[0]);

                })
```

Comment: The issue I can not retrieve the query value in the last console.log .. How could I get the password?

Comment: String concatenation -> SQL Injection alert. And please do not store password as plain text.

Comment: I do not understand .. How to do so? .. I can not retrieve the value of x which is the result of a SQL Query

Comment: @isodino Print your raw MySQL query to the console and you will see why it does not behave as you expect.  You never escape the username with single quotes, but don't do that anyway, use parameters instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using parameters in your query, i.e.

```
let x = tempCont.query('SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = ?',
    [req.body.user_name],
    function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in user_name Query');
        }
        else {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

By passing the username variable as a parameter in the array the proper escaping should already be done for you.

Comment: sorry I tried it .. but it gave me undefined value ...

Comment: when we use the inner console.log with result[0].role it gives a value .. When we try to get the value from x variable in the outer console.log .. it gives undefined.. the issue I do need to get the value from the variable

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but if no error occurred then `result` should contain your result set.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
var x = 0;

tempCont.query('SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` =' + req.body.user_name,
            function (err, result, field) {
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log('Error in user_name Query');
                }
                else {
                    console.log(result);
                }    

                x = result

                // to display password of row 1
                console.log(x[0].password);

                // to display row 1
                console.log(x[0]);

                // to display the object
                console.log(x);

            })
```

Also use this format:

```
tempCont.query('SELECT password FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = ?',[req.body.user_name],(err, result, field){
});
```

Comment: it is not working .. I can not get the value of the query through variable x

Comment: try running console.log(result) in the function, does your desired result show up in the terminal?

Comment: yes it appears but i do need it outside the function of query

Comment: how about passing only the password

    x = result[0].password

since its seems that you are only trying to get 1 password

Comment: var x = 1;
var y = 0;

 var z =connection.query ('SELECT * from `roles` where `id` = '+x , function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    
    console.log (results[0].role);
   y=results[0].role;
   console.log (y);
   return y;
});
console.log(y);
console.log(z);

Comment: Here z shows object .. while y inside query shows a specific value .. I can not get the specific value outside the query

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I use the data of the query and use it externally. Used it like an external module.

```
function fuser(req,res,next){
  var db = require('../../lib/database')();
  db.query("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE strSNum= ?",[req.params.userid], (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      req.user= results;
      return next();
    });
}

router.get('/:userid', fuser, (req, res)) => {
   res.render('profile/views/index',{usertab: req.user});
});
```

In this case, assigning the results object to req.user, but this example uses express

Comment: ok how do i use promise?

Comment: in your example .. i can not also console.log of req.user outside the function or the query